# Django DRF: read_only_fields not working properly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have the following models

```
class Breed(models.Model)::
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Pet(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        "User",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    breed = models.ForeignKey(
        "Breed",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

I am trying to add few fileds for `representation` purpose. I dont want them to be included while `create` or `update`

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_email = serializers.CharField(source='owner.email')
    breed_name = serializers.CharField(source='breed.str')
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ["breed_name","owner_email"]
```

This is not working. I see the `owner_email` and `breed_name` in the HTMLform (the DRF api page)

Where as

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_email = serializers.CharField(source='owner.email',read_only=True)
    breed_name = serializers.CharField(source='breed.str',read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = "__all__"
```

This is working. I dont see them in the HTMLform

Also i observed, if i use a model field directly in read_only_fields then it works.

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ["name"]
```

This will make all `name` not shown in update or create

Why `read_only_fields` is not working properly

Comment: Able to replicate this. Still looking at the source code why it's happening. But in the meantime you can set `read_only=True` or change the field to a `SerializerMethodField` which is always read-only

Comment: Ok. Great. I wanted to check the source code. But some how Sublime Text 4 is not navigating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very interesting. I looked into the code and found the root cause, specifically this [lines](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L1041-L1045) in the implementation for [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer):

```
for field_name in field_names:
    # If the field is explicitly declared on the class then use that.
    if field_name in declared_fields:
        fields[field_name] = declared_fields[field_name]
        continue

    ....
```

Here was my script for the investigation

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers


class MyModel(models.Model):
    xero_contact_id = models.UUIDField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Some name")
    class Meta:
        db_table = "my_model"


class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_email = serializers.CharField()
    breed_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ["breed_name", "owner_email", "xero_contact_id"]


serializer = MySerializer()
print(repr(serializer))
```

I added some prints and here is what I saw:

```
>>> print(repr(serializer))
field_names ['id', 'owner_email', 'breed_name', 'xero_contact_id', 'name']
declared_fields OrderedDict([('owner_email', CharField()), ('breed_name', CharField(max_length=255))])
extra_kwargs {'breed_name': {'read_only': True}, 'owner_email': {'read_only': True}, 'xero_contact_id': {'read_only': True}}
MySerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    owner_email = CharField()
    breed_name = CharField(max_length=255)
    xero_contact_id = UUIDField(read_only=True)
    name = CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
```

As you can see, the `read_only` argument is in the `extra_kwargs`. The problem is that for all the fields that are only declared in the `ModelSerializer` itself (visible from `declared_fields`) and not in the model class, they don't read from the `extra_kwargs`, they just read what was set in the field itself as visible in the code snippet above `fields[field_name] = declared_fields[field_name]` then performs a `continue`. Thus, the option for `read_only` was ignored.

I fixed it by modifying the implementation of `ModelSerializer` to also consider the `extra_kwargs` even for non-model fields

```
for field_name in field_names:
    # If the field is explicitly declared on the class then use that.
    if field_name in declared_fields:
        field_class = type(declared_fields[field_name])
        declared_field_args = declared_fields[field_name].__dict__['_args']
        declared_field_kwargs = declared_fields[field_name].__dict__['_kwargs']
        extra_field_kwargs = extra_kwargs.get(field_name, {})

        # Old implementation doesn't take into account the extra_kwargs
        # fields[field_name] = declared_fields[field_name]

        # New implementation takes into account the extra_kwargs
        fields[field_name] = field_class(*declared_field_args, **declared_field_kwargs, **extra_field_kwargs)
        continue

    ....
```

Now, `read_only` was correctly set to the target fields, including non-model fields:

```
>>> print(repr(serializer))
field_names ['id', 'owner_email', 'breed_name', 'xero_contact_id', 'name']
declared_fields OrderedDict([('owner_email', CharField()), ('breed_name', CharField(max_length=255))])
extra_kwargs {'breed_name': {'read_only': True}, 'owner_email': {'read_only': True}, 'xero_contact_id': {'read_only': True}}
MySerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    owner_email = CharField(read_only=True)
    breed_name = CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)
    xero_contact_id = UUIDField(read_only=True)
    name = CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
```

This doesn't seem to be in the DRF docs. Sounds like a feature we can request to DRF :) So the solution for the meantime is as what @JPG pointed out, use `read_only=True` explicitly in the extra non-model fields.

Answer (score 4):

The ***`read_only_fields`*** meta option will work for the fields which are ***not explicitly defined in the Serializer***.

So, in your case, you need to add the **`read_only=True`** to those explicitly defined fields, as

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_email = serializers.CharField(source='owner.email', read_only=True)
    breed_name = serializers.CharField(source='breed.str', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Can you show the link where this is written

Comment: I think its not written anyware. Maybe you can create a PR to do the same

Comment: Where did you find it